# What is the best way to insert 6000000 records from one table to another table in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Hello guys i need to copy 6000000 rows from TMP_DATA to DATA what is the best way to do this?

I was thinking of doing `INSERT INTO DATA SELECT * FROM TMP_DATA`. But i think it will take ages to do the insert.

What do you suggest?

Kind Regards,

Comment: That's probably the best way, and it shouldn't take ages (6 million rows isn't that many), unless you have lots of triggers and indexes and whatnot on the receiving table (and/or unless the update is over a slow network).

Comment: Are there more than 6,000,000 rows on TMP_DATA?  there are a couple ways to limit the number of rows; the `SAMPLE` clause of the select or `where rownum < 6000001` -- but if you are concerned simply about speed, Andres' answer below is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on Anders' answer and mathguy's comments, do the following:

```
alter table data nologging;
alter session enable parallel dml;
-- disable any triggers on `data` and temporarily drop any indexes

insert /*+ append */ * into data 
select /*+ parallel (4) */ * from tmp_data
--sample (10)  -- if tmp_data has 60 million rows: 10 means 10%
-- where rownum < 6000001 
-- pick one of the two prior clauses if tmp_table has > 6 million rows
```

after the insert is done:

```
alter table data nologging;  
-- enable triggers and recreate indexes
```

and have the dba do a backup as the `data` table will *not* be able to be recovered if there was any issue after the load.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

If you want speed use parallel and nologging so (on a new table):

-- Caveat:  this method is fast but will use a lot of cpu resources so just let

-- the DBA  know.  Also, index the table at the end.

```
create table DATA SELECT parallel 4 nologging as
select * from TMP_DATA;
```

If you are using an existing table one of the things that could potentially decrease the insertion performance is the use of indexes.  You can temporarily disable the index to allow faster insertions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You seem to have provided a valuable answer. However, you want to familiarize yourself with code formatting (hint: `{ }` button). And what's the purpose of the double dashes (--) in the middle of the sentence?